# .Net 6 Blazor Server-Side CSS Isolation not working

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I created a new .NET 6 Blazor Server-side project and made a couple of changes. I have a couple of files using CSS isolation (like Contact.razor + Contact.razor.css).. In the _Layout.cshtml page the template added the following:

```
<link href="CustomerPortal.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Where CustomerPortal is my Project Name. I can see the file is generated correctly under "CustomerPortal\CustomerPortal\obj\Debug\net6.0\scopedcss\projectbundle\CustomerPortal.bundle.scp.css" and "C:\Data\Git\WebApps\CustomerPortal\CustomerPortal\obj\Debug\net6.0\scopedcss\bundle\CustomerPortal.styles.css"
BUT when I run the project, both with Kernel or IIS Express, I get a 404 not found for the CSS, if I try to manually navigate to the CSS I also can't find it. Any ideas? My csproj doesn't have any flags that would affect it.

Comment: Long shot but - any sort of preprocessing happening that you've added that is throwing errors?

Comment: You mean like SCSS or SASS? I don't have anything like that, just plain CSS. Also, no errors besides the 404 itself

Comment: It seems if I switch my Environment to be "Development" instead of "Local" it is working again.. I experienced something similar on a .NET 5 Blazor application and I had to add webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets() on the Program.cs file, but on .Net 6 we don't have that file and that CreateHostBuilder anymore..

Comment: That makes sense for the exact reason you described. If you want static assets to be published in non-default environments (like "Local) you need to invoke that UseStaticWebAssets on webbuilder. Even with the minimal file structure, you can still access the host context.

Comment: Ok, that helps! I think understand what's going on now, I saw a lot of other users having similar issues on GitHub. The problem is how do I make that call? I tried builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets(); on my Program.cs and that didn't work, it errors out on runtime with: "System.NotSupportedException: 'The web root changed from "C:\Data\Git\WebApps\CustomerPortal\CustomerPortal\wwwroot" to "C:\Data\Git\WebApps\CustomerPortal\CustomerPortal\". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.'"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit:
[There is a new extension as part of the minimal setup in .NET 7, and backported to newer versions of .NET 6 as well.](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/26751)

Both in .NET 7 and .NET 6 you can now do:

`builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();`

Old answer:

You've got a couple options here to resolve this depending on the approach you want to take. I think we've figured out why it's happening, but `UseStaticWebAssets()` seems to not be supported for the new minimal startup code. So, here's your options I can think of off the top of my head.

1. Migrate your code back to the "old" way of doing application startup. This is still a supported and completely valid approach as there's edge cases that aren't supported (like this one).
2. Pass a new `WebApplicationOptions` to the `CreateBuilder()` method and, depending on environment, look for the static files in a separate (and correct) location. See [some examples here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#change-the-web-root)
3. With the existing `builder`, check the environment and use the `StaticWebAssetsLoader` to load static web assets.

A complete example of #3

```
if (builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("Local"))
{
    StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);
}
```

That being said - I'd imagine they'll plug this hole eventually and provide parity for `UseStaticWebAssets()`. You can see the progress of this effort in [this open GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38212).

Comment: Would you expect to have to add that `if` block for the 'Production' environment? I was expecting 'Production' to be a default environment and to handle isolated css bundling automatically, but it doesnt unless I add that `if` block

Comment: Correct, it should work by default if your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is set to Development, and all other environments it needs manually called. If you're using this for production, you've likely done something you shouldn't be. Upon publish, static web assets are placed in `wwwroot` and served from there - you shouldn't need to use `.UseStaticWebAssets()`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else...
I had the exact same issue with a .net 6 blazor server app. For me it came down to the fact that I had changed the project name but the reference to {project}.styles.css in _Layout.cshtml was still pointing to the old project name.
Simply updating {project} here to the correct project name fixed my issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this error, it was because I'd named my MVC project with a hyphen: `htmx-spike`.

When I generated the project from a template (`dotnet new mvc -o htmx-spike`), the tooling renamed the *namespace* to `htmx_spike`—with an underscore instead of a hyphen, because hyphens aren't allowed in C# identifiers—and used that modified name as the CSS filename in `_Layout.cshtml`.

[image: Link elements screengrab with incorrect file name "htmx_spike.styles.css"]

However, it turns out that in this case the CSS location actually still corresponds with the project name, *with* the hyphen. So the auto-generated code is incorrect, and was causing the 404 to be returned:

[image: Chrome dev tools network tab showing 404 error for "htmx_spike.styles.css"]

Once I renamed the file in the `link` element to the correct name with the hyphen, everything was fine.

[image: Chrome dev tools network tab showing 200 OK response for "htmx-spike.styles.css"]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a component I imported from another project.  I solved it by closing all instances of Visual Studio, deleting the hidden folder [.vs] from the project folder, and then restarting the project in Visual Studio.  On restart, Visual Studio recreated that folder and imported CSS file(s) were included.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to srHunter, this issue started after I had renamed the project.  It worked fine in a Debug build, but the CSS Isolation was missing from the Release build.  In my case, closing Visual Studio, deleting the .vs, bin and obj folders resolved my problem.  FWIW, deleting the .vs and bin folders weren't enough.  It only started working after I deleted the obj  folder also.

Comment: For y'all that don't know what FWIW means: **for what it's worth**