# Blazor server CSS isolation not working in Chrome

Tags: blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-css-isolation

I am trying to use CSS isolation and came across a similar problem as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70009382/2490877) - basically, my isolated styles are not applying.

However, I realized, when testing different browsers, that it works with Firefox and Edge, but not with Chrome. Is this a known limitation of Chrome? Or is there some specific code to add to make it work with Chrome?

Comment: Did you start with a fresh project, or try to add isolated files to an older project?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I added it to an existing project which initially had some isolated css.

Comment: The three problems I've had with isolated .css: 1) not having the right library linked in my Host page, because I adapted an existing project improperly; 2) not copying the constructed `Styles.css` file in wwwroot on deployment; 3) not knowing that instant hotload of changed .css wouldn't work-- it required a recompilation.  My guess is that Chrome has cached Styles.css and you need to do a hard reload.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 - I doubt ANY of the above is the issue, since it works with Firefox or Edge - it really only occurs with Chrome!

Comment: Did you delete Chrome's cache?

Comment: Indeed cache was the issue here.... thx !!!

Answer (score 1):

Manually clearing the cache worked.

Generally, it also helps to add css versioning when declaring the file, as for example

```
<link href="MyApplication.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
<!-- it also helps for other custom css files.... -->
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Credit to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224255/blazor-css-file-not-updating-when-app-is-launched).

Comment: I'm glad the cache clear helped, but that link is not the one that was problematic.  For isolation, Blazor makes another file `wwwroot/PROJECTNAME.styles.css`

Comment: You are right I copied the wrong css line - but it also helped adding the `asp-append-version="true"` to other files though, so I leave it in the answer!
Cheers!